# Cake php 2x is not detecting ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp

I have an api in one server and view file on the other. When i use ajax request, the value for

```
$this->request->is('ajax')
```

is always showing false. But it works fine in local xampp server. I have also enable the origin for the requesting server. What should i do. Is it due to cross domain.

my ajax from view is

```
$.ajax(
            {
                url:'http://12.34.567.890/Users/getu.json',
                // url:'<?php echo URL; ?>Users/getu.json',
                type:"POST",
                data:{access_token:'<?php echo $_SESSION["token"]->access_token; ?>', api_key:"***************"},
                async:false,
                success:function(res)
                {
                    console.log(res);
                }
            });
```

However i have found the main problem is that when in live server the ajax request does not have the headers

```
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest;
```

so, therefore cake could not recognize the ajax request.

Comment: Are you using the requesthandler component in your controller? `public $components = array('RequestHandler');`

Comment: Yes, i have it in my appController.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably in your ajax call. When you're doing the request, what's the dataType you're using? **If you need to do cross domain ajax call, you've to use [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) as dataType in your ajax call like this:**

```
$.ajax( {
   url: 'http://my_remote_server/controller/action',
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success: function( res ) {
      // do stuff with res
      alert("Success");
   },
   error:function() {
      alert("Error");
   }
} );
```

Then in your controller->action use the following to detect the ajax request:

```
if( $this->request->is( 'ajax' ) ) {
   // process the request and send output
}
```

Comment: I don't need to include dataType as jsonp since i have already allowed the access-origin to the requesting domain.